# An error has occurred: sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.get_entity' was never awaited

Tags: python, telegram-bot

An error occurs

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.get_entity' was never awaited
```

Now I'm doing a bot for Telegram. To work with the Core API, I use the Telethon library for Python 3.
Line of code:

```
username = 'channel' # channel @telegram
dp = client.get_entity(username)
```

I read the documentation, but I didn't understand why it doesn't work. Documentation -https://telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/chats-and-channels.html
I'm a beginner, please help me explain why it doesn't work and how to fix it. Thanks
Version Telethon 1.24.0
Python 3.9
IDE PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that your problem is that you are not awaiting a coroutine. So I'm guessing the `client.get_entity` is not a normal function but an asynchronous coroutine. You can learn more about coroutines here in the python [coroutines and tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine) documentation and perhaps you can read more about async in general and python `asyncio` .

In that case when you call `client.get_entity` it returns a coroutine but doesn't schedule it in the event loop for it to be actually run. For that to happen you'll have to explicitly create a task using `asyncio.create_task` or add the `await` keyword.

```
dp = await client.get_entity(username)
```

going through the [Getting entities](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html) section in the `Telethon` documentation you can see examples of usage of the function with `await`